# position_dodge works differently for height and width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to dodge points on a categorical y-axis and I'm hitting my head against something.

```
library(ggplot2)

foo <- data.frame(x1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2),
                  x2 = rep(LETTERS[3:4], times = 2),
                   y = rnorm(4))

ggplot(foo) + geom_point(aes(y = x1, x = y, color  =x2),
                           size = 4)
```

[image: first plot]

my question--i want the points to dodge along the y-axes by color

```
ggplot(foo) + geom_point(aes(y = x1, x = y, color  =x2),
                         size = 4,
                         position=position_dodge(height = 0.6))
```

[image]

but as you can see, there's no change.

f I want to dodge width by a categorical x axis, this code works now:

```
ggplot(foo) + geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y, color  =x2),
                         size = 4,
                         position=position_dodge(width = 0.6))
```

[image]

something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. You could add `coord_flip()` to your last plot as a work-around